# Intellij is not willing to import settings inside a zip file anymore?

Tags: intellij-idea

I have been exporting/importing JetBrains settings from various machines/versions/even apps (e.g. Intellij to Pycharm or vice-versa) for many years.

Why is this `Manage IDE Settings | Export setting` from `Pycharm` not being recognized during `Manage IDE Settings | Import settings` by `Intellij` ?

[image]

**Updates**

Settings that are exported:

[image]

*Versions*:

Versions: `Pycharm Ultimate 2022.2.1`   `Intellij Ultimate 2022.2.1`

Comment: Can you please provide a settings archive you're trying to import? You can use JetBrains [Upload Service](https://uploads.jetbrains.com/) and post an ID you'll receive here. Also, please, specify versions of both IDE you use; it can help reproduce your issue.

Comment: @EgorKlepikov  Versions and the settings being exported are added to the question. I will see when have time to go to the upload service

Comment: Does it help if you manually add `.zip` extension to the end of the file name when exporting settings? E.g. `pycharmSettings.1009.zip`

Comment: Oh i did try that as well - but did not update my screenshot. It did not work

Comment: I wasn't able to reproduce it from my side. Please upload your settings.zip to the upload service. Check if the problem reproduces in the EAP build from https://www.jetbrains.com/resources/eap

Comment: @EgorKlepikov  2022_10_12_YLj2RscMXZnZCSfVGAf4r